# Negative binomial random effects models (glmmTMB/gamm/gamm4)

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, mgcv, glmmtmb, gamm4

Can anyone help please. Am I missing something fundamental here?

I would like to test for a Cave and a Category effect in the same model, and 
I'd like to know if I've specified the random effects correctly.

I have nightly bat calls from 10 Caves, 3 successive Years, and several nights per Year (not always successive).
The Caves are one of two types, TypeA or TypeB,  Counts range from <10 to > 48,000 per night.

Each Cave was measured in every Year, but Caves are either of TypeA or TypeB.
There is a lot of variation between Caves and between Years.

```
str(bats)
'data.frame':   221 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Cave    : Factor w/ 10 levels "CO-CA-01","CO-CA-03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   
 $ Category: chr  "TypeB" "TypeB" "TypeB" "TypeB" ...  
 $ Year    : int  2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...  
 $ fYear   : Factor w/ 3 levels "2017","2018",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
 $ calls   : int  519 556 297 195 162 181 130 94 49 42 ...  
 $ lat     : num  -21.4 -21.4 -21.4 -21.4 -21.4 ...  
 $ long    : num  150 150 150 150 150 ...  

# Using glmmTMB;
# I would like to test Cave and Category in the same model   
# but I can't get this model to converge.  
# Model convergence problem; extreme or very small eigen values detected.
mod1 <- glmmTMB(calls ~ fYear*Cave +  Category, family="nbinom1",data=cor) 

# Testing for a Cave and Year effect without Category works fine;
mod2 <- glmmTMB(calls ~ fYear*Cave, family="nbinom1",data=bats) 

# Testing for a Category effect alone works fine.
# crossed random effects; multiple observations in every Year in every Cave.
mod3 <- glmmTMB(calls ~ Category + (1|fYear) + (1|Cave),family="nbinom1",data=bats) 

# Using mgcv
# Cave and Category in the same model;
# Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
M1 <- gamm(calls ~ Category + Year*Cave + s(lat,long, k=4,bs="ts"), 
           family=negative.binomial(1),data=cor,niterPQL=2000,method="REML")

# Category and Year works fine
M2 <- gamm(calls ~ Year*Category + s(lat,long, k=4,bs="ts"), correlation=corCAR1(form=~1|Year*Cave),random=list(Cave=~1),
           family=negative.binomial(1),data=cor,niterPQL=2000,method="REML") # works but with warning, residuals bad.

# Cave and Year works fine
M3 <- gamm(calls ~ Year*Cave + s(lat,long, k=4,bs="ts"), correlation=corCAR1(form=~1|Year*Cave),
           family=negative.binomial(1),data=cor,niterPQL=2000,method="REML")

# Using gamm4
#  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
M1 <- gamm4(calls ~ Category + s(lat,long, k=4,bs="ts"), random = ~(1+Cave|Year), 
            family=negative.binomial(1),data=cor,niterPQL=2000,method="REML")
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your research question for this modelling, Lisa? Can you update your post to include it?

Comment: The research questions are (i) Are number of calls different by Cave? and (ii) Are number of calls different by Category?